# How do I use grep command to search in .bz2.gz.bz2 file?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, terminal

Basically I have .bz2.gz.bz2 file which on extraction gives a .bz2.gz file and on again extraction gives .bz2 file. In this .bz2 file, is my txt file which I want to search on using grep command. I have searched for this but I got bzgrep command which will only search in bz2 file and not the corresponding .gz.bz2 file and give me no results.

Is there a command in unix system which will recursively search in a zipped archive for zipped archive and return results only when it finds the txt file inside it?

P.S: the txt file may be deep in the archive to level 10 max. I want the command to recursively find the txt file and search for the required string. And there will be no other than an archive inside the archive until the txt file level.

Comment: Really wondering what's a point to have `.bz2.gz.bz2` files...

Comment: No, there are no tools for such strange situation. I think there is no other way than a loop that analyzes the file; if it is compressed decompress it, if it is not does grep on it. The analysis can be done just on the file name, if it is reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand but maybe this will help:

```
for i in /path/to/each/*.tar.bz2; do 
tar -xvjf "$i" -C /path/to/save/in
rm $i
done

extract all `tar.bz2` and save them in directory then remove the `.bz2`
```

Answer (score -2):

Thnx for sharing your question.

There are a couple of strange things with it though:

- It makes no sense to have a `.bz2.gz.bz2` file, so have you created this file yourself? If so, I'd advise you to reconsider doing so in that manner.
- Also, you mention there is a `.bz2` that would apparently contain different archives, but a `.bz2` can only contain one single file by design. So if it contains archives it is probably a `.tar.bz2` file in which the tar-file holds the actual archives.

In answer to your question, why can't you write a simple shell script that will unpack your `.bz2.gz.bz2` into a `.bz2.gz` and then into a `.bz2` file and then execute your bzgrep command on that file?

I do not understand where it is exactly that you seem to get stuck..